# Search for files with more than one term (grep, awk?)

Tags: linux, grep, sed, awk

I am using a command like this to find files with the word 'term' in them:

```
grep -l term *
```

But I now want to be able to find files which have two different words in them (let's call them termA and termB) - not necessarily on the same line.  I want to find files with **both** terms in, not just files that have either term.

Now I could write a cumbersome bash script for this, but does grep, egrep, awk, sed or anything else have a tool that can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### If your files contain no null bytes

In this case, you can use `grep` alone:

```
grep -Plz "termA.*termB|termB.*termA" *
```

How it works:

- The [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) `termA.*termB` and `termB.*termA` search for strings which have both terms in it.
- The combined PCRE `termA.*termB|termB.*termA` matches all strings containing both terms.
- Finally, the `-z` switch makes data lines end in null bytes instead of newlines.

By the way, there's no *need* to use `-P`. If you prefer to continue using [POSIX Basic Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions), the syntax is similar:

```
grep -lz "termA.*termB\|termB.*termA" *
```

#### If your files contain null bytes

In this case, you'll need auxiliary tools:

```
(grep -l termA * ; grep -l termB *) | sort | uniq -d
```

How it works:

- `grep -l termA * ; grep -l termB *` displays all files containing either of the terms. Files that contain both terms will be displayed twice.
- `sort` sorts the output.
- `uniq -d` only displays duplicate lines (required lines to be sorted).

Comment: Thanks - this is looking for the terms to be on the same line though.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that requirement. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Tnanks Dennis.  The uniq -d was what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either the `-e` or `-f` options to search for multiple expressions (from `man grep`):

```
    -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
          Use  PATTERN  as  the  pattern.   This  can  be  used to specify
          multiple search patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with
          a hyphen (-).  (-e is specified by POSIX.)

   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
          contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
          specified by POSIX.)
```

So you would use this as:

```
$ grep -e termA -e termB *
```

Comment: Thanks. Not quite what I'm after. Your example (with -l to display the files) will give me files tat have either termA or termB in them.  I want a list of files that have both terms in.

Answer (score 1):

grep supports regular expressions as far as I know. I use the following syntax to search multiple terms:

```
    grep 'termA\|termB' /i/am/a/path
```

you do need to use the escape character '\' before each '|' but with that I bvelieve you can use as many search strings as you want

Comment: Sorry, I've clarified it in the question now, but I'm after a list of files with **both** terms in.  This would give me a list of files with either in.